# OpenVPN headless on Debian 11.7 IP does not change

Tags: networking, debian, vpn, openvpn

I have a ProtonVPN paid account.
I want to use it on my VPS server (so in headless), to change my ip.

Their client does not work in headless mode, so I use OpenVPN.

I download the Linux config file on ProtonVPN.
I installed ProtonVPN and resolvconf.

When I launch :

```
sudo openvpn conf_vpn.ovpn
```

It seems to work :

```
2023-07-31 11:21:54 DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'AES-256-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM). Future OpenVPN version will ignore --cipher for cipher negotiations. Add 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers or change --cipher 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers-fallback 'AES-256-CBC' to silence this warning.
2023-07-31 11:21:54 OpenVPN 2.5.1 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on May 14 2021
2023-07-31 11:21:54 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022, LZO 2.10
2023-07-31 11:21:54 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
2023-07-31 11:21:54 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC authentication
2023-07-31 11:21:54 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC authentication
2023-07-31 11:21:54 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]146.70.194.98:51820
2023-07-31 11:21:54 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
2023-07-31 11:21:54 UDP link local: (not bound)
2023-07-31 11:21:54 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]146.70.194.98:51820
2023-07-31 11:21:54 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]146.70.194.98:51820, sid=69f07161 a4eee661
2023-07-31 11:21:54 VERIFY OK: depth=2, C=CH, O=ProtonVPN AG, CN=ProtonVPN Root CA
2023-07-31 11:21:54 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=CH, O=ProtonVPN AG, CN=ProtonVPN Intermediate CA 1
2023-07-31 11:21:54 VERIFY KU OK
2023-07-31 11:21:54 Validating certificate extended key usage
2023-07-31 11:21:54 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Client Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
2023-07-31 11:21:54 ++ Certificate has EKU (oid) 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
2023-07-31 11:21:54 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) 1.3.6.1.5.5.8.2.2, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
2023-07-31 11:21:54 ++ Certificate has EKU (oid) 1.3.6.1.5.5.8.2.2, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
2023-07-31 11:21:54 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
2023-07-31 11:21:54 VERIFY EKU OK
2023-07-31 11:21:54 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=node-fr-21.protonvpn.net
2023-07-31 11:21:54 WARNING: 'link-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='link-mtu 1633', remote='link-mtu 1634'
2023-07-31 11:21:54 WARNING: 'tun-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='tun-mtu 1532', remote='tun-mtu 1500'
2023-07-31 11:21:54 WARNING: 'comp-lzo' is present in remote config but missing in local config, remote='comp-lzo'
2023-07-31 11:21:54 Control Channel: TLSv1.3, cipher TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 4096 bit RSA
2023-07-31 11:21:54 [node-fr-21.protonvpn.net] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]146.70.194.98:51820
2023-07-31 11:21:55 SENT CONTROL [node-fr-21.protonvpn.net]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
2023-07-31 11:21:55 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,dhcp-option DNS 10.16.0.1,sndbuf 524288,rcvbuf 524288,redirect-gateway def1,explicit-exit-notify,comp-lzo no,route-gateway 10.16.0.1,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-restart 60,socket-flags TCP_NODELAY,ifconfig 10.16.0.8 255.255.0.0,peer-id 6,cipher AES-256-GCM'
2023-07-31 11:21:55 Options error: option 'dhcp-option' cannot be used in this context ([PUSH-OPTIONS])
2023-07-31 11:21:55 Options error: option 'redirect-gateway' cannot be used in this context ([PUSH-OPTIONS])
2023-07-31 11:21:55 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
2023-07-31 11:21:55 OPTIONS IMPORT: explicit notify parm(s) modified
2023-07-31 11:21:55 OPTIONS IMPORT: compression parms modified
2023-07-31 11:21:55 OPTIONS IMPORT: --sndbuf/--rcvbuf options modified
2023-07-31 11:21:55 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->425984] S=[212992->425984]
2023-07-31 11:21:55 OPTIONS IMPORT: --socket-flags option modified
2023-07-31 11:21:55 NOTE: setsockopt TCP_NODELAY=1 failed
2023-07-31 11:21:55 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
2023-07-31 11:21:55 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
2023-07-31 11:21:55 OPTIONS IMPORT: peer-id set
2023-07-31 11:21:55 OPTIONS IMPORT: adjusting link_mtu to 1656
2023-07-31 11:21:55 OPTIONS IMPORT: data channel crypto options modified
2023-07-31 11:21:55 Data Channel: using negotiated cipher 'AES-256-GCM'
2023-07-31 11:21:55 Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
2023-07-31 11:21:55 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
2023-07-31 11:21:55 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
2023-07-31 11:21:55 net_iface_mtu_set: mtu 1500 for tun0
2023-07-31 11:21:55 net_iface_up: set tun0 up
2023-07-31 11:21:55 net_addr_v4_add: 10.16.0.8/16 dev tun0
2023-07-31 11:21:55 /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf tun0 1500 1584 10.16.0.8 255.255.0.0 init
resolvconf: Error: Command not recognized
Usage: resolvconf (-d IFACE|-a IFACE|-u|--enable-updates|--disable-updates|--updates-are-enabled)
2023-07-31 11:21:55 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
2023-07-31 11:21:55 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

But if I let this Terminal tab open, and open a new one connecting by ssh, and run :

```
curl -s https://ipinfo.io/ip
```

My IP has not changed at all.

I see that I have the error :

```
resolvconf: Error: Command not recognized
```

But when I launch (with or without sudo) :

```
sudo /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf tun0 1500 1584 10.20.0.8 255.255.0.0 init
```

it seems to work because I don't have any warning.

What did I forget ?